# Possible way to add multiple git repositories in the same Google cloud project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-source-repos

Is there a way to add multiple git repositories in the same Google cloud project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently cannot do this.  We know this is a useful feature, and we're working hard on it. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 5):

We've added the ability to have multiple Cloud Source Repositories for every cloud project.

You can read about how to add a new repo to your project here: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/setting-up-repositories

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of doing this as of today. Every project can only have one `remote` repository.

Answer (score 2):

Every Google cloud project can only have one **remote** repository.

However, t's definitely possible to have multiple **local** repositories that correspond with the same **remote** Google cloud repository.

[**The official documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-quickstart) describes the following procedure for how to use a Cloud Source Repository as a remote for a local Git repository :

> #### Create a local Git repository
>
> Now, create a repository in your environment using the Git command
>   line tool and pull the source files for a sample application into the
>   repository. If you have real-world application files, you can use
>   these instead.
>
> ```
> $ cd $HOME
> $ git init my-project
> $ cd my-project
> $ git pull https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-helloworld-python
> ```
>
> #### Add the Cloud Source Repository as a remote
>
> Authenticate with Google Cloud Platform and add the Cloud Source
>   Repository as a Git remote.
>
> On Linux or Mac OS X:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud auth login
> $ git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
> $ git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/<project-id>/
> ```
>
> On Windows:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud auth login
> $ git config credential.helper gcloud.cmd
> $ git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/<project-id>/
> ```
>
> The credential helper scripts provide the information needed by Git to
>   connect securely to the Cloud Source Repository using your Google
>   account credentials. You don't need to perform any additional
>   configuration steps (for example, uploading ssh keys) to establish
>   this secure connection.
>
> Note that the `gcloud` command must be in your `$PATH` for the
>   credential helper scripts to work.

It [**also explains**](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository) how to create a local git by cloning a Cloud Source repository :

> #### Clone a Cloud Source Repository
>
> Alternatively, you can create a new local Git repository by cloning
>   the contents of an existing Cloud Source Repository:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud init
> $ gcloud source repos clone default <local-directory>
> $ cd <local-directory>
> ```
>
> The `gcloud source repos clone` command adds the Cloud Source
>   Repository as a remote named `origin` and clones it into a local Git
>   repository located in `<local-directory>`.

Comment: Yes but the question is can you have multiple remote repos inside of a project.

So something like `/p/<project-id>/<repo-name>`

Answer (score 2):

Git submodule should do the trick. Add git repositories as submodules.

See

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule
- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't, but you can use `Git subtree merges` to add multiple "subrepositories" as folders in your main repository, which will do the trick.

See details here https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/

(There are also `submodules` as @Shishir stated, but as I understand they are only set for your current local clone and won't be included in checkouts/clones done by others, so I think submodules won't work).

Comment: git clone --recursive https://github.com/chaconinc/MainProject would get submodules. There are other ways also, but i find this to be the easiest.